# Lucenet.net query with mutilple field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, lucene.net

I have following query in my SQL Server stored procedure.

```
(Venue like '%arizona%' or keyword like '%arizona%' or location like '%arizona%') 
and (location like 'tempe') and (author like '%autorr%')
```

I want to produce same result using lucene.net. Please provide me sample query to produce this result.

Thanks

Comment: [What have **you** tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) SO is **not** a code-writing service - shows us some effort of your own - we'll be glad to help with concrete issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty simple. I used following way to compose lucene.net query

```
(Venue:arizona OR keyword:arizona OR location:arizona) 
AND (location:tempe) AND (author:autorr)
```

I passed this string to parser object and retrieve desire results.